# I want to be a freelance web designer. What other up to date technologies/skills would you add to this list?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Technologies I need to know: HTML, HTML5, CSS, CSS3, jQuery, CSSLESS, ASP.NET, SQL, WordPress, PHP

Skills needed: media querys/responsive design, browser compatability, graphic design, user interface design, typography, accessability

Answer (score 3):

Add more?

You have too much as it is.

Start with HTML,CSS and JavaScript. Then choose between ASP and PHP (ASP and PHP only because those are you mentioned, there is many more options like Ruby, Python etc etc...) for backend, and of course you will need SQL.

Once you comfortable with HTML, CSS and JavaScript, you can learn one of JS libraries like JQuery, and take a look at CSS pre-processing (LESSCSS or SASS).

And when you are decent at all above, you can start adding more things to list. And at that point you will know yourself what to do next.